# Harvesting Rocky Mountain Bee Plant

Tags: planting, harvesting, wildflowers

[image: Rocky Mountain Bee Plant Cleome serrulata]
I am looking to harvest the seeds from a patch of these Rocky Mountain Bee Plants for replanting. I have never seen them before in 30 years in my area hence why I am interested. Based on this photo when would be the ideal time to pick these pods. Should all the flowers be gone and should the pods be dry?

Comment: Ideally you'd want the seed pods to be dry. The concern is that they'd open and drop their seeds before you can get to harvest them. A nice workaround is to tie a mesh bag around them to catch the seeds if they fall.